# boot2docker Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

I saw a similar question but it was related to the newer `docker-machine` so it's not duplicate.
So, basically what I've done - I removed docker VM (boot2docker-vm) from Virtual Box then recreated it using `boot2docker init`, started it and after that I'm getting the error on any `docker` command:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

no matter what I tried, even full reinstall using homebrew. I'm able to login to this machine using `boot2docker ssh`, I can check its IP addresses and check that daemon is running there on the required port. Also I ensured that `DOCKER_HOST` points to the correct address/port. Could somebody provide an idea what else I could check or the direction in which I should work?

UPD:
I found out that I'm able to login on boot2docker-vm, though I checked ports and IPs there and they are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the future generations - in my case it was caused by Cisco VPN enabled on time of VM creation. To solve that I did the following steps:

- VirtualBox > Preferences > Network and deleted all host-only networks
- deleted boot2docker-vm
- `$ boot2docker init`
- `$ boot2docker up`

After that everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the user you are logged in as has permission to execute Docker commands. Perhaps prefixing your `boot2docker init` command with `sudo`. That would mean executing the following command:

'sudo boot2docker init'

Or you can make sure the user you are logged in as has permission to execute Docker commands by assigning your local user permissions using this statement in your command-line:

`sudo usermod -aG docker ' *[userid]*